# Postgresql and QT

Tags: sql, qt

Не могу добавить данные в таблицу выдает данную ошибку

```
QSqlError("42601", "QPSQL: Unable to create query", "ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: \"(\")\nСТРОКА 1: EXECUTE  ('rrrr', 'test', 'gggg', 'technician', '2018-11-28'...\n                   ^\n(42601)")
```

Вот сам код

```
db.setDatabaseName("request");                 
QString name = ui->name_l->text();
QString ipn("test");
qDebug()<<ipn<<db.databaseName();
QDate date = QDate::currentDate();       
QString description = ui->problem_t->toPlainText();
QString category = ui->category_cb->currentText();
QString spec_ipn = ui->ipn_line->text();
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO requests (name,ipn,description,category,date,source,spec_ipn)"
              "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
query.bindValue(0,name);
query.bindValue(1,ipn);
query.bindValue(2,description);
query.bindValue(3,category);
query.bindValue(4,date);
query.bindValue(5,"client");
query.bindValue(6,spec_ipn);
bool qur = false;
qur= query.exec();
QMessageBox msgbx;
if(qur == true)
{
    QMessageBox::information(nullptr,"Инфо", "Запрос успешно отправлен!");
}
else
{
   QMessageBox::warning(nullptr,"Предупреждение", "Невозможно добавить запрос!");
}

qDebug()<<qur<<query.lastError()<<"\n"<<query.lastQuery();
QFile file("log.txt");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Text);
QTextStream instream(&file);
instream<<query.lastError().text()<<"\n"<<query.lastQuery();
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку **и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить bindValue на addBindValue )

Comment: А может быть колонки в таблице перепутаны